# Show stdout in file and in console (with System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File("output-file.txt"))

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I want to save the stdout into a file. For this, I used 
`System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File("output-file.txt")));`

Now, there is no output in the console.

```
        try {
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File("output-file.txt")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Is there any possibility to show the stdout in the console, although I use stdout to fill a file?

Comment: Use `System.out.println()` to print output to console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a `PrintWriter` with an `OutputStream` that does both writes.

```
final OutputStream stdOut = System.out;
try {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
        private PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(new File("output-file.txt"));

        @Override
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            ps.write(b);
            stdOut.write(b);
        }

        @Override
        public void flush() throws IOException {
            super.flush();
            ps.flush();
            stdOut.flush();
        }

        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            super.close();
            ps.close();
            // stdOut.close(); // Normally not done
        }
    }));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.out.println("Hello, world!");
```

Comment: Thanks for help. It is working :)

I have just one question: 

I want to add a timestamp at the beginning of each System.out.println. like: 2018-01-15 --> "here a text"

But the PrintStream object and the Output Stream object are working with integer. Do I have to parse the timestamp into integer?

Comment: @Makuna Hmm, that seems like a tricky thing indeed. Presonally, I would just create a helper class that you can then call instead of `System.out.println`. Or you could subclass the `PrintStream` itself instead of the `OutputStream` inside of it; then you'll have a lot more methods to work with. Of course I don't know your use case, so it's hard for me to give an exact solution. If you get stuck in developing this, you should probably ask a new question, since it is basically a new problem.

Answer (score 1):

I never tried it, but i guess if you subclass the default Printstream you are able to print to console and file by yourself.

Something like:

```
class MyPrintStream extends printStream {

    private PrintStream secondPrinter;

    .....

    @Override 
    public void println(Object content) {
       super.println(content);
       secondPrinter.println(content);
    }
}
```

and maybe call it like this:

```
System.out = new MyPrintStream(myFile, System.out);
```

Comment: The downside of this solution: you need to override every method you want to use. like println, print, flush, close etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the systems `OutputStream` to write to 2 sources. It is a static variable and it **can only have 1 value at a time.**

You can try however, saving a reference to the consoles default `OutputStream`, and then changing the Systems `OutputStream` to your custom output stream, and write to both of them with a custom method.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new subclass of the PrintStream class and then override it's methods to write to a second Stream and then pass that to System.out as you've already one.
Further reading & example implementation: https://books.google.ch/books?id=lbnjAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA326&ots=j7OUeuXzIa&dq=java%20duplicate%20printstream&pg=PA326#v=onepage&q=java%20duplicate%20printstream&f=false